# Instant Preview on only certain content

Tags: lyx

I am working in LyX, learning as I go. Is it possible to enable instantpreview on only certain parts of an equation?

For example, I have `\newcommand{\aug}{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}` to create an augmented matrix like:

```
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 2 & \aug & 0\\
2 & -1 & 1 & \aug & 1\\
4 & 1 & 5 & \aug & 1
\end{pmatrix}
```

I'd like it if instantpreview only were enabled for the `\aug` commands.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

A. You can choose to preview only certain math insets by selecting the math equation and going to Insert > Preview. To do this, go to Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Display and set "Instant preview" to "No math". For this option, the entire math inset is previewed. In your example, the entire matrix would be previewed (but you can choose not to preview other matrices or math insets).

B. You can use LyX macros, which will give you a sort of WYSIWYM preview in this case. Here are
the steps:

1. First, remove your custom LaTeX code `\newcommand`. (you can leave your `\aug`s)
2. Go to Insert > Math > Macro.
3. In the "name" field put `\aux`.
4. In the "TeX" field put `\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!`.
5. In the "LyX" field, put "|".

This gives the following display in LyX:

[image]

For more information on LyX macros, see the corresponding section in Help > Math.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should have mentioned in my original post that I already tried A. Unfortunately, the preview inset wraps the entire math inset. I can't just select the `\aug`s.

Comment: @Oliver Even if you could preview just the `\aug`s I'm not sure it would get you any closer than the LyX macro approach. That is, I'm not sure that LyX would know that the `\aug`s are supposed to be connected. The preview mechanism in LyX is that it generates the preview and then just displays the preview in the LyX display as an image. LyX would thus view the `\aug` as an image, its algorithms (which provide a reasonable first approximation to the LaTeX algorithms) would not take into account the properties of the TeX of the `\aug` definition.